# How to effectively follow new updates on several question tags without external tools?

Tags: support, tags, tag-watching, discussion

How would I most efficiently follow the newest questions on SO? As I have understood you can have a feed of them, but is it possible to look the feed with some StackExchange tool?

One idea would be to have the newest ones coming to your inbox of SO, but it would not be more easy than looking the questions freely. I am also waiting my points to grow so much that I get rid of the ads, then the ads don't make me scroll when tapping tags on the right pane.

Is there another SO features or ideas how to more effectively follow many question updates of different tags simultaneously? What strategies / tools you're using when your interest is on several tags? I want to use the SO only, not mixing any external tools (only if they are superb ones).

Comment: Have you seen the [tag filters](http://stackexchange.com/filters/popular) on http://stackexchange.com/, you could create your own set and use that? I'm not sure if this counts as "SO only".

Comment: As long as you don't consider it unethical, you don't have to wait for your reputation to grow in order to get rid of the ads: any adblocking browser extension can take care of that ;)

Comment: @DMA57361: Write the same to an answer and I'll accept it. You get the points (if you're collecting..)

Comment: if you consider it answer-worthy, then it is done. :)

Comment: see http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/04/improved-tag-sets/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you aware of the [tag filters](https://stackexchange.com/filters/popular) available over on https://stackexchange.com/?

They provide you with a list of active, new or unanswered questions based on a set of tags and sites that you can define, and there are also two defaults available as well which collect everything on your sites or your favourite tags across the network.