# Filter new questions based on favourite tags

Tags: support, tags, filtering

On the Stack Overflow questions page (https://stackoverflow.com/questions) any new questions that have my favourite tags are shown with a pink background. Is it possible to filter new questions based upon my favourite tags? (So only the ones which now have a pink background show up)

So for example I have as my favourite tags: [java](/questions/tagged/java) and [matlab](/questions/tagged/matlab), so can I filter the results on the main page to only show questioned tagged with [java](/questions/tagged/java) and [matlab](/questions/tagged/matlab).

This question is a possible duplicate of [How to effectively follow new updates on several question tags without external tools?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94503/how-to-effectively-follow-new-updates-on-several-question-tags-without-external/94903#94903) but that question seems to have largely dead links so I presume the system has changed.

I realise I could just jam all my favourite tags into the search bar but that’s going to become increasingly onerous the more favourite tags I have (especially for mobile use).

Comment: There is another one, but even older: [Tab for questions that are labeled with favorite tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11563/tab-for-questions-that-are-labeled-with-favorite-tags)

Comment: @stema Yes, that is indeed what I'm looking for, shame it was declined. I wish they'd say why things are status declined

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can't direct filter new questions based on favorite tags but we can filter questions based on few tags. E.g. if you want to get all questions tagged with [java](/questions/tagged/java) or [matlab](/questions/tagged/matlab) you can filter it using: `/tagged/java+or+matlab` in the URL

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+or+matlab?sort=newest

Comment: This is exactly what I do, and added bookmarks to my browser toolbar...

Answer (score 2):

Another view, that is closer to what you want, is the ["interesting" Tab](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=interesting).

This filters the incoming questions with [a complicated algorithm](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/), based on your favourite tags (what you want) and your top 40 scoring tags (and some other criteria).

Comment: Interesting, I think I stumbled on that tab once before but could never get back to it. Other than following your link how do I get to the interesting tab; its not a tab on the main page

Comment: O, thats embarrising, if you just put in http://stackoverflow.com/ it defaults to it

Comment: In my experience the algorithm is not great; maybe your mileage is better. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100321/why-are-most-interesting-so-questions-not-even-remotely-interesting-to-me

Comment: You can get it by clicking on the Stackoverflow logo left to the "Questions" button.

Comment: If this worked properly I think this would be exactly what I want, sadly I agree with @AaronBertrand it doesn't really work for me either

Comment: My experience has been the opposite, and all of the "interesting" questions have at least been relevant, if not necessarily interesting, to me. That might be because pretty much all of my activity is in the jquery and javascript tags anyway though.

Answer (score 2):

If you click on the Unanswered button up top (not to be confused with the Unanswered tab), there is a tab for "My Tags"

The only problem with it is it doesn't appear that you can customize what and how questions are displayed. It only shows questions without an upvoted or accepted answer, and the questions are sorted by votes.

https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=mytags

(Maybe it's time for a feature request to expand on the viewing options here?)

---

You can also find a list of questions filtered by your favorite tags if you login to [stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/), click "Filtered Questions", then click on the "Favorite Tags" filter on the right side of the screen.

https://stackexchange.com/filters/favorite-tags

Of course, this isn't really the same as it uses the color scheme for Stack Exchange instead of SO, and shows you your favorite questions from all SE sites (although I think you can filter it for just SO).

I can't really pinpoint what it is, but I find this method much harder to use for browsing questions on the stack exchange network, so I never use it.

Comment: Interesting, how strange that its there for unanswered but not for the general questions button

Comment: @RichardTingle I recall reading a meta post once that said they intentionally try to present users with a variety of questions to entice them to participate in other tags, or to give lesser-known tags a chance at getting answers. The Unanswered question list is probably treated slightly differently since the primary goal of the site is to provide answers to programming problems, so allowing users to filter by what they want to answer when they go looking for unanswered questions seemed like a good idea.

Comment: I think I found it... there is a deleted answer by Jeff Atwood on [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11563), which says *"We believe that browsing by tag, and tag combination, should be sufficient. The bleedthrough and forced exposure to other topics is intentional; we believe programmers have more in common across languages and disciplines than they think they do. We don't want to create more "ghettos" where programmers only care about or look at certain pet topics.

Good programmers are well-rounded, and are aware of the world outside their "special preferred" tag.*"

Comment: A fair point, although it has the reverse effect for me, I specifically search for my special interest tags and very rarely look at my mild interest tags

Comment: @RichardTingle I am the same way, and so are a lot of other users on the network. That answer from Jeff was at +4 and -17 when he deleted it, and there was a lot of comments posted on it arguing against Jeff's point of view. I understand it, but that doesn't mean I like it :)

Comment: Right, in spite of Jeff's wish to make everyone a well-rounded programmer across impossible disciplines, I will never find a Java or Ruby on Rails or jQuery question "interesting."

Comment: @AaronBertrand I'm not sure I can forgive such a slight to Java. Before java, programming was just a tool to me. To be more reasonable (and I'm not sure I like being reasonable) I use Java exclusively for hobby programming and other languages for work so perhaps I have a rose tinted view